# Component OLE DB Source has duplicate column reference with name ErrorCode on output Error

Tags: ssis, biml

I am fetching data from SQL server via OLE DB Source component. I am getting error as in below screen shot

[image]

The table design in SQL server is as below.

[image]

The column **ErrorCode** causing the issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a first. I say this because I have never pulled in a column name of `ErrorCode` and `ErrorDescription` from an OLEDB Source. The pipeline engine reserves those two columns internally in the event errors occur. Looks like you will need to alias those columns in your dataflow as `ErrorCodeDb` and `ErrorDescriptionDb` for use within the pipeline and then map those columns back to the database.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I later figured it out aliasing of columns in select query did the trick for me.